# Which dissimilarity index to use with categorical ecological data

Tags: r, matrix, bioinformatics, distance

I am currently working on data representing the abundance of microorganisms in a categorical way, like 0 = no organisms; 1 = 1-5 organisms; 2 = 6-10 and so on (5 being the highest number).
And i am not quite sure which dissimilarity index is best to use with vegdist for that kind of data, to then do Pcoa etc.
So i wanted to ask if someone has any experience and could recommend an index?

Thanks in advance!

When first looking at the data i tried Bray-Curtis dissimilarity, but i found that it is not right with my kind of data. I already googled a bit and found the Gower-distance do be more appropriate, but not exactly fitting.

For reference, that what the data is looking like:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDoKt.png)